# Simplification of Addition of Radicals

Tags: radicals

I know this may be a basic question, but I cannot seem to get the right simplification process for the following equation:

$\sqrt{36+64+5^2} + \sqrt{20}$

I do know that the correct answer is `7√5`, but I cannot seem to arrive at this answer.

This is how I broke it down.

Option 1:

```
√105 + 2√5
```

Option 2:

```
√100 + 5 + 2√5
10 + 5 + 2√5
15 + 2√5
```

I appreciate feedback on where I made a mistake.

Comment: $10+5+2\sqrt{5}$ is not $17\sqrt{5}$ because $15+2\sqrt{5} \neq 17\sqrt{5}$.  You need $15\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{5}$ to get $17\sqrt{5}.$

Comment: Did you mean $\sqrt{36 + 64 + 5^2} + \sqrt{20}$?  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site, then edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $36+64+5^2=125,$ not $105$.  Then $\sqrt{125}=5\sqrt 5$ and $\sqrt{20}=2\sqrt 5$ so the sum is $7\sqrt 5$

Comment: Thank you. All along I thought that the exponent of 2 gets canceled out when the number is squared.

Comment: If you have $\sqrt{(stuff)^2}$ the square root and the square cancel (but watch out for the absolute value).  In this case the $5^2$ is part of stuff, the whole of stuff is not squared, so we need to evaluate stuff before we take the square root and the square does not cancel.

Comment: Yes, I realized that as well. Thank you.